# Remove bottom line in Custom Header's tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with Custom Headers but I can't remove the bottom white line inside. The Separator property is set to none, in fact, the cells in the section don't have the line.

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DashboardSectionHeader";
UITableViewCell *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    ...
    return headerView;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 60;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try return height 55 in heightForHeaderInSection and see if the line still appears.

Comment: It appears with any height

Comment: Did you try setting separator color to clear color?

Comment: @tnylee yes but it doesn't work

Comment: I think your tableviewCell is having a one pixel space at the top.Just check.

Comment: @abhi1992 I don't think because the background color of tableview is dark, like the background color of the cell and container view. In fact the line is inside the section block, not between it and cell.

Comment: Have you checked DashboardSectionHeader cell?If there is a line at the bottom.Try changing the backgroundcolor of this cell and see.There can be many possibilities.I am just saying. :)

Comment: @abhi1992 Thanks, I (you :D) found the problem. In interface builder, the background of DashboardHeader is clearColor, but if I change it to yellow, the line becames yellow. The strange thing is that the contentView is different. How can I change color of them both programmatically? Thanks

Comment: @abhi1992 ok found: headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

Comment: @abhi1992 If you want, answer the question and I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked `DashboardSectionHeader` cell?If there is a line at the bottom.Try changing the backgroundcolor of this cell and see.If the line is appearing in the section view ,then there should be say a one pixel space at the bottom of this cell through which the background will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in the same circumstances as you, and for me the problem have been solved by adding:

```
cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

in `tableView: viewForHeaderInSection:` method. Or you can just uncheck `Clip Subview` property in `Attribute Inspector` for your cells Content View (in Storyboard or xib file). FYI, I kept this property checked for my TableViewCell.